# Scraping #document from an iframe tag using beautifulsoup

Tags: python, dom, beautifulsoup, python-requests, screen-scraping

I am trying to scrape a [website](https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/25/covid-world-map-countries-most-coronavirus-cases-deaths) for COVID related data. The data is enclosed in an `iframe` tag. I tried to scrape the results using `beautifulsoup` but couldn't extract `#document`. Here's my approach

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
with requests.Session() as s:
    coo = s.get("https://www.theguardian.com/", headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})
    cookies = dict(coo.cookies)
    url = "https://www.theguardian.com/world/2020/oct/25/covid-world-map-countries-most-coronavirus-cases-deaths"
    webpage = s.get(url, headers={'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'}, cookies = cookies)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(webpage.content, "html.parser")
    frame = soup.find("iframe", class_ = "interactive-atom-fence")
    print(frame)
```

My results:

[image: The end part]

Inspect Data from website:

[image: Website HTML code]

Can somebody explain that why the `#document` part is missing from my results?

Comment: Turn off `JS` (JavaScript) on the page you're scraping and see for yourself. `BeautifulSoup` doesn't *see* dynamic content. Hence your lack of results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

However, `The Guardian` offers an entire `.csv` file up for grabs, if you take a look at what's going on in the Developer Tool.

Here's how to grab data for `Covid19 Gloabal Deaths`:

```
import shutil

import requests

url = "https://interactive.guim.co.uk/2020/coronavirus-jh-timeline-data/time_series_covid19_deaths_global.csv"
data = requests.get(url, stream=True)
if data.status_code == 200:
    with open("covid19_data.csv", 'wb') as f:
        data.raw.decode_content = True
        shutil.copyfileobj(data.raw, f)
```

And if you swap the last part of the `URL` with `time_series_covid19_confirmed_global.csv` that's what you're going to get back as a `.csv` file.